# How to import multiline text into a database?

Tags: python, sql-server, regex, import, notepad++

I'm trying to import tabular data from a PDF into a database (MS Access or SQL Server Express). The data looks sort of like this:

```
NAME                        ID    EDUCATION      YEAR
--------------------------- ---- -------------- --------
Doe, John                   123   Elementary     2000
  New York, NY                    H School       2004
                                  Undergrad      2008
--------------------------------------------------------
Furter, Frank               345   Elementary     2010
  Los Angeles, CA                 H School       2014
--------------------------------------------------------
Chiever, Hiya               456   Elementary     2000
  Washington, DC                  H School       2003
                                  Undergrad      2006
                                  Masters        2008
                                  PhD            2010
--------------------------------------------------------
Walker, Julie               234   Elementary     2000
  Chicago, IL                     H School       2004
                                  Undergrad      2008
                                  Masters        2010
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Copying the content and pasting into Excel gives me approximately one line per item so it looks like this:

```
Doe, John
New York, NY
123
Elementary 2000
H School 2004
Undergrad 2008
```

I would like any suggestions to get this into a normalized RDBMS. My thoughts are:

1 - See if SQL Server Management Studio still supports javascript coding for data imports (I remember doing that 20 years ago) but I don't remember if it requires a defined number of lines per record.

2 - Hack the data up in Notepad++ with a bunch of Find & Replace commands so it turns into one row per person.

3 - Inject XML tags using Notepad++ and do an XML import into an RDBMS.

Any other suggestions for converting/importing? I know someone with OmniPage Ultimate which might be useful but I don't know enough about it do decide either way. I also have a friend who knows Python well - would this be a good project for me to start learning on? Thanks!

Comment: You can copy it to Notepad++ or SublimeText3 (my favorite), discover patterns in it (like each column is separated by a tab) and then so a regex replace. This is what I do systematically. I import tables into the DB by copying the data into a text editor. Then I find patterns and replace the text with several fully built INSERT statements. Then just copy and paste the result into the SQL console.

Comment: The main thing here is to find the patterns in the copied text. In SublimeText3 I usually select the text and the tabs are represented as lines and the spaces as dots. I don't know how that works in Notepad++, though.

Comment: Trying to recover original formatting from the raw text is a wrong way to go. First use a proper extracting tool like [pdftotext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext), that can preserve the layout, then try to build upon the results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with `Python`, here's an approach using quite some programming logic.  This might be **way over the top** and you should definitely look for ways to get the information with other tools.

That being said, you could build yourself a class that gets the length for every column, splits the string into several records (separated by `---` on both sides), transforms each record into a matrix of different columns (four in this case) and finally yields a dict for each record.

---

In `Python`:

```
class cleanItems:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
        self.cols = self.getColumnWidths()

    def getColumnWidths(self):
        ''' Get the length of every column '''
        rx = re.compile(r'^(NAME\s+)(ID\s+)(EDUCATION\s+)(YEAR\s+)', re.M)
        match = rx.search(data)
        if match:
            return [len(group) for group in match.groups()]

    def getEntries(self):
        rx = re.compile(r'^[ -]+$', re.M)
        for record in rx.split(self.string):
            # discard empty lines and the header
            lines = [line for line in record.split('\n') if line.strip()]
            if len(lines) > 1:
                matrix = [[line[sum(self.cols[0:i]):sum(self.cols[0:i+1])] 
                            for i in range(len(self.cols))] 
                            for line in lines]

                result = {'name': matrix[0][0].strip(), 'id': matrix[0][1].strip(), 
                            'town': matrix[1][0].strip(), 'school': [matrix[i][2].strip() for i in range(len(matrix))],
                            'years': [matrix[i][3].strip() for i in range(len(matrix))]}
                yield result

ci = cleanItems(data)
for record in ci.getEntries():
    print(record)
```

This yields

```
{'name': 'Doe, John', 'id': '123', 'town': 'New York, NY', 'school': ['Elementary', 'H School', 'Undergrad'], 'years': ['2000', '2004', '2008']}
{'name': 'Furter, Frank', 'id': '345', 'town': 'Los Angeles, CA', 'school': ['Elementary', 'H School'], 'years': ['2010', '2014']}
{'name': 'Chiever, Hiya', 'id': '456', 'town': 'Washington, DC', 'school': ['Elementary', 'H School', 'Undergrad', 'Masters', 'PhD'], 'years': ['2000', '2003', '2006', '2008', '2010']}
{'name': 'Walker, Julie', 'id': '234', 'town': 'Chicago, IL', 'school': ['Elementary', 'H School', 'Undergrad', 'Masters'], 'years': ['2000', '2004', '2008', '2010']}
```

And you can easily feed this into your database or an `XML` file.